# Can people see the hours and minutes on my commits on Github?

Tags: git, github

I browsed around Github but I cannot find a way to view what hour someone submitted a commit, say 3 months ago.

Is there a way to do this online on the GitHub site?

Comment: @dystroy I specifically stated I want to view commits in the context of Github. Not git cli.

Comment: @rightføld Any repository on Github

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 That's a very weird definition of "submit"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using GitHub

Comment: @Abizern I don't think GitHub is really out of topic (11.9k questions already).

Comment: @Abizern Talking about tools (i.e. GitHub, Git) that developers use is not offtopic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Reopened. Github is obviously topical, and even has a tag. Editors are also topical and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many people will browse the history after having locally cloned the repository. All commands like `git log` and `git show` display the precise date.

When you're browsing online, just hover the date :

[image]